# Make mpc command on linux outout only number of progress for the song?

Tags: linux

While a song is playing through mpd; When i type this command:

```
mpc | sed 's/.*(//;s/)//;2q;d
```

I get the progress percentage; How can i remove the percentage symbol as well and only keep the numbers?

Comment: Sorry, but this command won't even run.
Please have a look into some documentation for `sed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse the order of characters in the string, remove the first character from the string, and reverse the order of characters to its original order again like so:

```
mpc | sed 's/.*(//;s/)//;2q;d' | rev | cut -c 2- | rev
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This is exactly what i need.

Comment: Please try to avoid answering off-topic questions. They should be closed or migrated instead. Posting answers only attracts more off-topic questions.